# iOS4.0: UIAlertView with UITextField messed up

Tags: uitextfield, ios4, uialertview

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/494c515b14.jpg]

this is what i get when using this code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rank on ScoreBoard: %d",positionOnBoard] message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil];
nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 25, 260, 21)];

[nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[nameField setPlaceholder:@"Your Name Here!"];

[alert addSubview:nameField];

[alert show];

[nameField becomeFirstResponder];

[alert release];
```

as you see, it's messed up.
it only happened when ugrading my project to iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved it by increasing the height of the UIAlertView by adding a "\n " (YES, it's a space after the \n) to the InitWIthTitle parameter, then i had enough space to place the UITextField correctly.

Comment: I found [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6866932/434423), rather lengthy, for inserting subviews into UIAlertView. The downside is that it has a nasty bug related to the overlay keyboard.