# Keyboard doesn't dismiss even when a UIResponder object resigns it's first-responder status

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextfield, first-responder

I managed to customize the UIAlertView putting two UITextFields as subviews inside of it but in doing so somehow the keyboard broke.

When I try to dismiss it resigning the first responder it doesn't do anything just stays there.

Here's my code, well, only relevant parts (this is what I put in a UIAlertView subclass):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    UIView *backgroundView = [subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect firstFrame = [[subviews objectAtIndex:2] frame];
    CGRect backgroundFrame = [backgroundView frame];
    CGFloat displacement = kTextHeight * 2 + kPadding * 3;
    CGFloat pivot = firstFrame.origin.y + firstFrame.size.height;
    CGRect nameFrame = CGRectMake(firstFrame.origin.x,
            pivot + kPadding,
            kTextWidth, kTextHeight);
    CGRect descriptionFrame = CGRectMake(firstFrame.origin.x,
            pivot + kTextHeight + kPadding * 2,
            kTextWidth, kTextHeight);

    if (_nameField == nil && _descriptionField == nil) {
        // first UITextField
        _nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_nameField setPlaceholder:kNamePlaceholder];
        [_nameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [_nameField setDelegate:self];
        // second UITextField
        _descriptionField =
                [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_descriptionField setPlaceholder:kDescriptionPlaceholder];
        [_descriptionField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [_descriptionField setDelegate:self];
        [self addSubview:_nameField];
        [self addSubview:_descriptionField];
    }
    // set the new frames to each text field
    [_nameField setFrame:nameFrame];
    [_descriptionField setFrame:descriptionFrame];
    // increment background image-view height by "displacement"
    backgroundFrame.size.height += displacement;
    [backgroundView setFrame:backgroundFrame];
    // displace by "diplacement" every subview positioned after "pivot"
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        CGRect viewRect = [view frame];

        if (viewRect.origin.y > pivot)
            [view setFrame:CGRectOffset(viewRect, 0., displacement)];
    }
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <UITextFieldDelegate>

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Here's my code in one big chunk:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

static CGFloat kTextWidth = 260.;
static CGFloat kTextHeight = 25.;
static CGFloat kPadding = 10.;
static NSString *kNamePlaceHolder = @"Name";
static NSString *kDescriptionPlaceHolder = @"Description";

// interfaces

@interface AppDelegate: NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *_window;
}
- (void)showAlertView;
@end

@interface AlertView: UIAlertView <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *_nameField;
    UITextField *_descriptionField;
}
@end

// implementations

@implementation AppDelegate

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AppDelegate

- (void)showAlertView
{
    AlertView *alertView = [[[AlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
            message:@"Body" delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alertView show];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <UIApplicationDelegate>

- (BOOL)            application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [_window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3. target:self
            selector:@selector(showAlertView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    return YES;
}
@end

@implementation AlertView

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_nameField setDelegate:nil];
    [_descriptionField setDelegate:nil];
    [_nameField release];
    [_descriptionField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    UIView *backgroundView = [subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect firstFrame = [[subviews objectAtIndex:2] frame];
    CGRect backgroundFrame = [backgroundView frame];
    CGFloat displacement = kTextHeight * 2 + kPadding * 3;
    CGFloat pivot = firstFrame.origin.y + firstFrame.size.height;
    CGRect nameFrame = CGRectMake(firstFrame.origin.x,
            pivot + kPadding,
            kTextWidth, kTextHeight);
    CGRect descriptionFrame = CGRectMake(firstFrame.origin.x,
            pivot + kTextHeight + kPadding * 2,
            kTextWidth, kTextHeight);

    if (_nameField == nil && _descriptionField == nil) {
        // first UITextField
        _nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_nameField setPlaceholder:kNamePlaceholder];
        [_nameField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [_nameField setDelegate:self];
        // second UITextField
        _descriptionField =
                [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_descriptionField setPlaceholder:kDescriptionPlaceholder];
        [_descriptionField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [_descriptionField setDelegate:self];
        [self addSubview:_nameField];
        [self addSubview:_descriptionField];
    }
    // set the new frames to each text field
    [_nameField setFrame:nameFrame];
    [_descriptionField setFrame:descriptionFrame];
    // increment background image-view height by "displacement"
    backgroundFrame.size.height += displacement;
    [backgroundView setFrame:backgroundFrame];
    // displace by "diplacement" every subview positioned after "pivot"
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        CGRect viewRect = [view frame];

        if (viewRect.origin.y > pivot)
            [view setFrame:CGRectOffset(viewRect, 0., displacement)];
    }
}


- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <UITextFieldDelegate>

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
@end

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
            NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    [pool drain];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: According to the UIAlertView Class Reference, you are not supposed to subclass it. Its subviews are private. If you want to have textfields in one, you can use one of the new `UIAlertViewStyle` choices, available on iOS5+. Check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to override `becomeFirstResponder` in the `UIAlertView` subclass:

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    // For some unkown reason UIAlertView can be first responder. Disabling
    // this completely fixes this bug http://stackoverflow.com/q/6866932/434423
    // BTW, overriding "canBecomeFirstResponder" to return "NO" doesn't work,
    // this is why we override this instead of "canBecomeFirstResponder".
    return NO;
}
```

I'll post all my code in case someone needs it. Properly handles UIAlertView customization.

---

**CustomizableAlertView.h**

```
@class UIAlertView;

@interface CustomizableAlertView: UIAlertView
{
    UIView *_customSubview;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *customSubview;
@end
```

---

**CustomizableAlertView.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "CustomizableAlertView.h"

static CGFloat kVerticalPadding = 10.;
static CGFloat kMinHorizontalPadding = 12.;
static NSString *kTransformKeyPath = @"transform";

@interface CustomizableAlertView (Private)

- (void)centerViewOnKeyboardDismissal:(UIControl *)control;
@end

@implementation CustomizableAlertView

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [_customSubview release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject (NSKeyValueObserving)

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    // Make sure we are observing kTransformKeyPath from self
    if (_customSubview != nil && self == object &&
            [keyPath isEqualToString:kTransformKeyPath]) {
        // We should remove the observing object to avoid a recursion
        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kTransformKeyPath];

        CGFloat displacement =
                [_customSubview frame].size.height / 2. + kVerticalPadding;

        [self setTransform:
                CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(.0, -displacement)];
        // Resume the observation
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:kTransformKeyPath options:0
                context:NULL];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIResponder

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    // For some unkown reason UIAlertView can be first responder. Disabling
    // this completely fixes this bug http://stackoverflow.com/q/6866932/434423
    // BTW, overriding "canBecomeFirstResponder" to return "NO" doesn't work,
    // this is why we override this instead of "canBecomeFirstResponder".
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
    UIView *messageView = nil;
    UIView *backgroundView = nil;

    // Perform a pattern search instead of depending on UIAlertView internal
    // structure.
    // This fetches the background view.
    for (UIView *view in subviews) 
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            backgroundView = view;
            break;
        }
    // Perform a pattern search instead of depending on UIAlertView internal
    // structure
    // This fetches the view that we'll use as an anchor.
    for (UIView *view in subviews)
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] &&
                [[(UILabel *)view text] isEqualToString:[self message]]) {
            messageView = view;
            break;
        }
    if (backgroundView == nil || messageView == nil)
        // Abort if there were no matches
        return;

    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
    CGRect messageFrame = [messageView frame];
    CGRect backgroundFrame = [backgroundView frame];
    CGRect customFrame = [_customSubview frame];
    CGFloat displacement = customFrame.size.height  + kVerticalPadding * 2.;
    CGFloat pivot = messageFrame.origin.y + messageFrame.size.height;

    // increment background image-view height by "displacement"
    backgroundFrame.size.height += displacement;
    [backgroundView setFrame:backgroundFrame];
    // displace by "diplacement" every subview positioned after "pivot"
    for (UIView *view in subviews) {
        CGRect viewRect = [view frame];

        if (viewRect.origin.y > pivot)
            [view setFrame:CGRectOffset(viewRect, .0, displacement)];
    }

    CGFloat maxWidth = bounds.size.width - kMinHorizontalPadding * 2.;

    if (customFrame.size.width > maxWidth)
        customFrame.size.width = maxWidth;
    [_customSubview setFrame:CGRectOffset(customFrame,
            (bounds.size.width - customFrame.size.width) / 2.,
            pivot + kVerticalPadding)];
    if ([_customSubview superview] == nil)
        [self addSubview:_customSubview];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // perform hit-test for every subview
    for (UIView *view in [self subviews])
        if ([view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view]
                withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIAlertView

- (void)show
{
    NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [defaultCenter addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(centerViewOnKeyboardDismissal:)
        name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(centerViewOnKeyboardDismissal:) 
            name:UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];
    // Dammit! we need to observe value-changes for the property "transform" to
    // handle properly the UIAlertView relocation.
    // We need to hang this onto "show" because UIAlertView's designated
    // initializer is imposible to override due to its variadic parameter (...).
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:kTransformKeyPath options:0 context:NULL];
    [super show];
}

- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
                             animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Cease to observe kTransformKeyPath upon dismissal
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kTransformKeyPath];
    [super dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:animated];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CustomizableAlertView

@synthesize customSubview = _customSubview;

- (void)centerViewOnKeyboardDismissal:(UIControl *)control
{
    CGRect bounds = [[self superview] bounds];

    [self setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds))];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a usage example:

---

**InputView.h**

```
#import "CustomizableAlertView.h"

@class UITextField;
@protocol UITextFieldDelegate;

@interface InputView: CustomizableAlertView <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    NSString *_placeholder;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *placeholder;
@end
```

---

**InputView.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "InputView.h"

static CGFloat kTextFieldHeight = 25.;
static CGFloat kHorizontalPadding = 12.;
static NSString *kDefaultPlaceholder = @"Enter text here";
// NSLocalizedString(@"Enter text here", nil)
static NSString *kPlaceholder;
static NSCharacterSet *kWhitespaceCharSet;

@interface InputView (Private)

- (void)initializeTextField;
@end

@implementation InputView

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSObject

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [InputView class]) {
        kPlaceholder = NSLocalizedString(kDefaultPlaceholder, nil);
        kWhitespaceCharSet =
                [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] retain];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if ([self customSubview] == nil)
        [self initializeTextField];
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CustomizableAlertView

- (void)setCustomSubview:(UIView *)view
{
    // NO-OP, should be readonly our control
}

- (UITextField *)textField
{
    return (UITextField *)[self customSubview];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark InputView

@synthesize placeholder = _placeholder;

- (void)initializeTextField
{
    UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc]
            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0.,
                    [self bounds].size.width - kHorizontalPadding * 2,
                    kTextFieldHeight)] autorelease];

    [textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [textField setPlaceholder:
            _placeholder == nil ? kPlaceholder : _placeholder];
    [textField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
    [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [textField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
    [textField setDelegate:self];
    // call the setter from the superclass becaused we overrode it to do
    // nothing
    [super setCustomSubview:textField];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark  <UITextFieldDelegate>

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([@"" isEqualToString:[[textField text]
            stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:kWhitespaceCharSet]])
        return NO;
    // The user pressed "Done" button, so dismiss the keyboard and return
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```